# How can I compare the ending of a word with a hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, hash

I'm trying to do something like a string analyzer and I need to retrieve the ending of a word and compare it with the keys of an hash

```rb
word = "Test"
ending_hash = {"e" => 1, "st" => 2}
output = 2
```

I need the output to be 2 in this case, but actually I won't know if the length of the ending is of 1 or 2 characters. Is it possible to do?

Comment: We'd like to see your effort toward solving this. Currently you've given us a requirement but show no code. See "[ask]" and its linked pages and "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, assume that you know that `word` ends with (at least) one of the keys of `ending_hash`. You can then write:

```
word = "Test"
ending_hash = {"e" => 1, "st" => 2}
```

```
ending_hash.find { |k,v| word.end_with?(k) }.last
  #=> 2
```

See [Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find), [String#end_with?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F) and [Array#last](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-last).

The intermediate calculation is as follows:

```
ending_hash.find { |k,v| word.end_with?(k) }
  #=> ["st", 2]
```

If you are unsure if *any* of the keys may match the end of the string, write:

```
ending_hash = {"e" => 1, "f" => 2} 
arr = ending_hash.find { |k,v| word.end_with?(k) }
  #=> nil
arr.nil? ? nil : arr.last
  #=> nil
```

or better:

```
ending_hash.find { |k,v| word.end_with?(k) }&.last
  #=> nil
```

Here `&` is the [Safe Navigation Operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/). In a nutshell, if the expression preceding `&` returns `nil`, the SNO immediately returns `nil` for the entire expression, without executing `last`.

Even if `word` must end with one of the keys, you may want to write it this way so that you can check the return value and raise an exception if it is `nil`.

You could alternatively write:

```
ending_hash.find { |k,v| word.match? /#{k}\z/ }&.last
```

The regular expression reads, "match the *value* of `k` (`#{k}`) at the end of the string (the anchor `\z`)".

Note the following:

```
{"t"=>1, "st"=>2}.find { |k,v| word.end_with?(k) }&.last
  #=> 1
{"st"=>1, "t"=>2}.find { |k,v| word.end_with?(k) }&.last
  #=> 1
```

so the order of the keys may matter.

Lastly, as the block variable `v` is not used in the block calculation, the block variables would often be written `|k,_|` or `|k,_v|`, mainly to signal to the reader that only `k` is used in the block calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there will be only a small number of *lengths* of endings, it is much faster to check for all possible lengths, than to check for all endings. (It also makes sense to check them from longest to shortest, in case they overlap, otherwise the shorter will never be matched.)

The lazy one-liner:

```
(-2..-1).lazy.map { |cut| ending_hash[word[cut..]] }.find(&:itself)
```

The functional version:

```
(-2..-1).inject(nil) { |a, e| a || ending_hash[word[e..]] }
```

The blunt but moist version:

```
ending_hash[word[-2..]] || ending_hash[word[-1..]]
```